# Boolean bitmap operation in .NET?

Tags: .net, bitmap, boolean

I have two 8bpp bitmaps.  I want to do a bitwise AND of one to the other, but I don't see any obvious way to do this in .NET.  Is it possible to do this without using non-.NET methods?
Thanks!

Comment: Is it 8bpp indexed?  That means there are 256 colors, but /which/ they are is specified in a separate table that each pixel indexes into.  .NET calls this Format8bppIndexed.

Comment: No, it's just one channel extracted from a deeper image.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure whether that is one of the supported PixelFormat values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx).

Comment: I may have to resort to this if I can't find a library method that does it.  Unfortunately looping in C# probably will execute slower.

Answer (score 3):

You could try converting the Bitmap to a Byte array and then loop through the bytes anding them together

Edit : 
Ran a Time Test on the loop idea:

Example Code:

```
DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
Image Image1 = Image.FromFile("C:\\Image1.bmp");
Image Image2 = Image.FromFile("C:\\Image2.bmp");
DateTime AfterLoad = DateTime.Now;
MemoryStream S = new MemoryStream();
Image1.Save(S, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
Byte[] I1 = S.ToArray();
Image2.Save(S, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
Byte[] I2 = S.ToArray();
DateTime AfterConvert = DateTime.Now;
DateTime AfterLoop = DateTime.Now;
if (I1.Length == I2.Length)
{
    Byte[] I3 = new Byte[I1.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < I1.Length; i++)
        I3[i] = Convert.ToByte(I1[i] & I2[i]);
    AfterLoop = DateTime.Now;
    FileStream F = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\jamesb\\desktop\\Image3.bmp", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    F.Write(I3, 0, I3.Length);
    F.Close();
}
DateTime Finished = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show("Load Time: " + (AfterLoad - StartTime).TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms" + "\r\n" +
                "Convert Time: " + (AfterConvert - AfterLoad).TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms"+ "\r\n" +
                "Loop Time: " + (AfterLoop - AfterConvert).TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms"+ "\r\n" +
                "Save Time: " + (Finished - AfterLoop).TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms"+ "\r\n" +
                "Total Time: " + (Finished - StartTime).TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");
```

with the following results :

```
Load Time: 30.003 ms
Convert Time: 94.0094 ms
Loop Time: 128.0128 ms
Save Time: 177.0177 ms
Total Time: 429.0429 ms
```

The images "Image1" and "Image2" were 4000 x 2250 (From a digital camera converted to 8 bit bmp)

Comment: An interesting approach.  Unfortunately looping is slow in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not important, use Bitmap.GetPixel and Bitmap.SetPixel

Comment: Unfortunately, these are very slow in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '[BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370(VS.85).aspx)' function, in which you can AND the source and destination (***SRCAND***), the pinvoke signature is [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/BitBlt.html).

Here is an article on Codeproject that uses a BitBlt wrapper [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Bitblt_wrapper_class.aspx).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: He asked to do it without using non-.NET methods.

Comment: @Matthew...unfortunately...there is a reliance on pinvoke to do some things that .NET cannot do....

Comment: There is no reason .NET can't do this.

Comment: @Matthew..is there a bitblt function in .NET?

Comment: I was hoping for a .NET mechanism.  But using BitBlt would probably be faster than anything I could do purely in .NET.  I may end up using this.  Thanks.

Comment: The fact that there is no BitBit function in the .NET library does not mean the task can't be performed in .NET.

Comment: I tried it but the only raster ops that worked were WHITENESS and BLACKNESS.  It might have been because one of the bitmaps I was using was an Aurigma bitmap (which handles the CMYK color space), which may not be 100% compatible with .NET bitmaps.

Comment: alankdkd: check out this conversion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259711/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-shape-with-a-cmyk-colour-fill-in-net from cymk to rgb...